# Polygon zkEMV-testnet Invalid SafeProxyFactory contract address

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am able to deploy a new SAFE on Polygon Mumbai using the SDK Quickstart instructions [here](https://docs.safe.global/learn/quickstart/different-ways-to-create-a-safe)

I am attempting to replicate that and launch a SAFE on Polygon zkEVM-testnet. When I deploy on polygon zkevm I receive the error:

`Error: Invalid SafeProxyFactory contract address`

So I went to the `safe-contracts` repo, and followed [the instructions there](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/tree/v1.3.0) and receive the following:

```
yarn deploy-all zkEVM_testnet                                                                                                                                                                                                      
yarn run v1.22.19
$ hardhat deploy-contracts --network zkEVM_testnet

Nothing to compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /home/hayek/proj/safe-contracts/src/deploy/deploy_accessors.ts:
Error: 
        Safe factory not found for network 1442. You can request a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory.
        For more information, see https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts#replay-protection-eip-155
```

So I follow the deployment request url, `https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory`, and I see in the expected deployer key address is `0xE1CB04A0fA36DdD16a06ea828007E35e1a3cBC37`.

I can confirm that address on mumbai, and polygon zkevm, but not on polygon zkevm-testnet. When I check the issue history I can see that polygon zkevm-testnet has been requested back in May in [this issue](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues/134).

Am I missing something, should I submit a new network support request? The expected factory address for zk-networks is `0xaECDbB0a3B1C6D1Fe1755866e330D82eC81fD4FD` and I can confirm it does not exist on zkevm or zkevm-testnet. The expected factory for vanilla evm, `0x914d7Fec6aaC8cd542e72Bca78B30650d45643d7`, appears to have a small contract. I am guessing it just reverts to avoid lost Eth?

Anyway I believe the error message is valid, I just want to understand if there is something special about polygon zkevm? I'm still ramping up a bit and would like to get a SAFE on polygon zkevm and zkevm-testnet.